# UseEffect is not triggering

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

so i used useeffect in my project and for some reason it ain't working. anyone that knows if i did. it is specifically the useeffect that is not triggering. the Console.log("Hi") does trigger everywhere else outside of useeffect.

```js
const [openRequests, setOpenRequests] = useState([]);
  const [answeredRequests, setAnsweredRequests] = useState([]);
  const [closedRequests, setClosedRequests] = useState([]);
  const [assignments, setAssignments] = useState([]);
  const [CompleteAssignments, setCompleteAssignments] = useState<
    CompleteAssignment[]
  >([]);

  const [omzet, setOmzet] = useState<number>(0);
  const [vooruitzicht, setVooruitzicht] = useState<number>(0);

  const history = useHistory();

  const BTN_AS = document.getElementById("Opdrachten");
  const BTN_OP = document.getElementById("OpenAanvragen");
  const BTN_WE = document.getElementById("GeweigerdeAanvragen");
  const BTN_GE = document.getElementById("GeslotenOpenAanvragen");
  const OmzetText = document.getElementById("OmzetText");

  const hide = (ID: string) => {
    let x = document.getElementById(ID);
    switch (ID) {
      case "Opdrachten":
        if (x!.style.display === "none") {
          x!.style.display = "block";
          BTN_OP!.style.display = "none";
          BTN_WE!.style.display = "none";
          BTN_GE!.style.display = "none";
        } else {
          x!.style.display = "none";
        }
        break;
      case "OpenAanvragen":
        if (x!.style.display === "none") {
          x!.style.display = "block";
          BTN_AS!.style.display = "none";
          BTN_WE!.style.display = "none";
          BTN_GE!.style.display = "none";
        } else {
          x!.style.display = "none";
        }
        break;
      case "GeweigerdeAanvragen":
        if (x!.style.display === "none") {
          x!.style.display = "block";
          BTN_AS!.style.display = "none";
          BTN_GE!.style.display = "none";
          BTN_OP!.style.display = "none";
        } else {
          x!.style.display = "none";
        }
        break;
      case "GeslotenOpenAanvragen":
        if (x!.style.display === "none") {
          x!.style.display = "block";
          BTN_AS!.style.display = "none";
          BTN_WE!.style.display = "none";
          BTN_OP!.style.display = "none";
        } else {
          x!.style.display = "none";
        }
        break;
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    async () => {
      console.log("hi");
      let completeAssignments: CompleteAssignment[] =
        await asyncCallApiByApiTag("getApiCompanyAanvragenGeslotenCompany");
      let openResults = await asyncCallApiByApiTag(
        "getApiCompanyRequestsOpenList"
      );
      let answeredResults = await asyncCallApiByApiTag(
        "getApiCompanyRequestsAnsweredList"
      );
      let closedResults = await asyncCallApiByApiTag(
        "getApiCompanyRequestsClosedList"
      );
      setOpenRequests(openResults);
      setAnsweredRequests(answeredResults);
      setClosedRequests(closedResults);
      setCompleteAssignments(completeAssignments);

      // console.log(CompleteAssignments);
      let result = await asyncCallApiByApiTag("getApiCompanyAssignmentsList");
      setAssignments(result);
      completeAssignments.map((result: any, index) => {
        completeAssignments.forEach((e) => {
          if (result["assignment"]["completedRequest"] == true) {
            console.log("brrrrrr");
            setOmzet(
              e["quotation"]["hoursPrice"] + e["quotation"]["materialPrice"]
            );
          }
        });
      });
      completeAssignments.map((result: any, index: number) => {
        completeAssignments.forEach((e: any) => {
          if (result["assignment"]["completedRequest"] == false) {
            console.log(completeAssignments);
            setVooruitzicht(
              e["quotation"]["hoursPrice"] + e["quotation"]["materialPrice"]
            );
          }
        });
      });
    };
  }, []);
```

what this should basically do is. get the data from my C# database and put that into the tables and display the price of stuff on the top. everything renders but the useeffect. so the whole functionality doesn't work now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to call an async func inside an `useEffect`, you need to define it and then call it. In your example, it seems that you forgot to call it

```
useEffect(() => {
   const fetch = async () => {
      // Your async code
      return []
   }
   fetch()
}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

You have written a function inside `useEffect`, there could have been a code block directly, instead of another function definition, or at least an IIFE.

Answer (score 0):

It *is* executing.  But... What is it doing?  Stripping out all of the other code, your `useEffect` function contains this structure:

```js
async () => {
  console.log('hi');
};
```

Which successfully executes.  But what does it *do*?  It defines an anonymous function which is never executed.  So your code is successfully... defining a function.

Presumably you meant to also execute that function.  Which you can do by making it an IIFE:

```js
(async () => {
  console.log('hi');
})();
```

Or perhaps giving the function a name and invoking it from that name:

```js
const myFunc = async () => {
  console.log('hi');
};
myFunc();
```